# can use 1 5/8 25ga metal studs to hang 5/8 drywall

Tags: drywall, basement, framing, metal

I came across free 1 5/8 metal studs 25ga.  Can I frame out my basement using them and attach 5/8 inch lightweight drywall to them.  The ceiling height is from 7-9 feet and some of the walls will end up being 35’ long.  I just wasn’t certain if the 1 5/8 will hold a single layer of drywall for me.

I would frame a couple of door ways with traditional 2x4s

Thank you !

Comment: https://www.bmp-group.com/docs/default-source/resource-library-literature/maximum-height-tables-for-interior-non-loadbearing-partitions5b4b45cfd1de6413ac21ff00002d9a3e.pdf?sfvrsn=0

Comment: https://www.avsforum.com/threads/1-5-8-steel-studs.1980073/ "Thank you for contacting ClarkDietrich Engineering Technical Support. Yes, ClarkDietrich’s 1 5/8" **20Ga** steel studs would be able to handle a double layer of 5/8" drywall. Although limiting heights are listed with one (l) layer of 5/8”, testing is done with 8 psf which is more than the one (1) layer." (5/8ths is 2.3 psf. The tables in the first link start at 5psf and go up. The problem is you have *25* gauge)